# List of alternates to check whether a link is working or not in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have lists of links and I need to check which of them are in the working state. I have a large amount of links probably in millions.

Problem is the link could be temporarily be disbaled
or link is temporarily broken
or is not reachable. 
In this case I do not want to remove the broken links.

I have tried using faraday but for working links also it gives 304, 301 and also takes time to get the response.
I need an alternative to check whether links are in working state or not in ruby.

```
response = Faraday.get 'http://www.google.com'
response.status
```

Need a way how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try two things:

1) Use [HTTP HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) that works like GET but fetches only headers, without any content (so it's faster):

```
response = Faraday.head 'http://www.google.com'
response.status
```

2) Check links in threads to make it parallel.

Comment: `s/Faraday.get/Faraday.head/` I suppose.

Comment: thanks, but I was wondering what about the scenario in which the link is temporarily not available. It might be available later on
or due to some network issue, it gets some other HTTP code.

Comment: You can retry them, e.g. check 2-3 times before deciding they're not valid

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way to check if a link is working is to make an HTTP request. Some server may implement HEAD so it responds with no content when it works. But that is not really a requirement.

One thing you can do is to manually drop the connection as soon as you get headers. This requires a bit more manual work compared to just wrap all the network into a simple method:

```
Net::HTTP.start(host, ...) do |http|
  http.request_get(path) do |response|
    response.read_body do
      # headers have been received, this block receives
      # each body chunk
      break
    end
  end
end
```

For instance

```
resp = Net::HTTP.start('www.google.com', use_ssl: true) { |http|
  http.request_get('/') { |resp|
    resp.read_body { break }
  }
}


resp.code

=> "200"

resp.each_header.to_a

=> [["date", "Mon, 21 Jan 2019 10:09:15 GMT"], ["expires", "-1"], ...]

resp['date'] # you can read headers in a hash-like way

=> "Mon, 21 Jan 2019 10:09:15 GMT"

resp.body

=> ""
```

So the body is not waited for, and you can check on headers to see if response was "successful". The http connection is dropped as soon as the first chunk of data is sent. If the server is not sending chunks, you will have to get all the response anyways.